# Creating a table gives a "missing right parenthesis" error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, ddl

I have been getting error "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" when I run this `create table` statement:

```
create table employee(
  primary key(emp_id number(20)),
  emp_name varchar(30),
  birth_date date CHECK(birth_date>18),
  gender varchar(10),
  dept_no number(20)
    CONSTRAINT fk FOREIGN KEY(dept_no)
    REFERENCES department(dept_no),
  address varchar(50),
  designation varchar(20)
    CHECK(designation IN('manager', 'clerk', 'leader', 'analyst', 'designer', 'coder','tester')),
  salary number(50)
    CHECK(salary>0),
  experience number(2),
  email_id varchar(30)
    CONSTRAINT chk_email
    CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(email_id,'^[A-Za-z0-9_.]+@[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$'))
);
```

I have looked up the exact syntax and after checking many times, everything seems to be just perfect but the error still exists. What is wrong?

Comment: If you want to check the age you'll have to do that in a trigger, not a constraint - you can't use a non-deterministic calculation (i.e. one based on sysdate where the result changes over time) in a check constraint.

Comment: @AlexPoole Putting date datatype here will fetch the date from system which ofcourse changes. everyday. So I will have to use trigger instead. This is what you are trying to convey if I am not wrong?

Comment: Yes - `birth_date date` is fine, but say `CHECK (months_between(birth_date, sysdate)/12 > 18)` would throw an ORA-02436 error. Even though in that specific case the check wouldn't changed from true to false in the future (no-one is getting any younger sadly) it's a blanket ban. So yes, you would have to check it in a trigger instead.

Comment: Now I understood it well. That was precise. Thanks a million @AlexPoole. Happy coding.:)

Comment: Stack overflow community has always been a major support. Truly, love to get guided by pro coders remotely. Thats such a privilage. Thank you once again @AlexPoole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little bit of

- invalid syntax (position of the primary key keywords),
- superfluous foreign key keywords (you'd use them *out of line*, not *inline*),
- check constraint for the `birth_date` column is wrong (how can date be larger than 18?),
- Oracle suggests us to use `varchar2` instead of `varchar`,
- `number(50)` has too large precision (perhaps you'd rather just skip it).

Once fixed (with a dummy master table):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE department
  2  (
  3     dept_no   NUMBER PRIMARY KEY
  4  );

Table created.
```

Employee:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE employee
  2  (
  3     emp_id        NUMBER (20) PRIMARY KEY,
  4     emp_name      VARCHAR2 (30),
  5     birth_date    DATE,
  6     gender        VARCHAR2 (10),
  7     dept_no       NUMBER CONSTRAINT fk_emp_dept REFERENCES department (dept_no),
  8     address       VARCHAR2 (50),
  9     designation   VARCHAR2 (20)
 10                     CHECK
 11                        (designation IN ('manager',
 12                                         'clerk',
 13                                         'leader',
 14                                         'analyst',
 15                                         'designer',
 16                                         'coder',
 17                                         'tester')),
 18     salary        NUMBER CHECK (salary > 0),
 19     experience    NUMBER (2),
 20     email_id      VARCHAR2 (30)
 21                     CONSTRAINT chk_email CHECK
 22                        (REGEXP_LIKE (
 23                            email_id,
 24                            '^[A-Za-z0-9_.]+@[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$'))
 25  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

---

As of a trigger that checks employee's age, here's how:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_bi_emp
  2     BEFORE INSERT
  3     ON employee
  4     FOR EACH ROW
  5  BEGIN
  6     IF MONTHS_BETWEEN (SYSDATE, :new.birth_date) < 18 * 12
  7     THEN
  8        raise_application_error (-20000,
  9                                 'Too young; must be at least 18 years of age');
 10     END IF;
 11  END;
 12  /

Trigger created.

SQL> INSERT INTO employee (emp_id, birth_date) VALUES (1, DATE '2020-07-25');
INSERT INTO employee (emp_id, birth_date) VALUES (1, DATE '2020-07-25')
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: Too young; must be at least 18 years of age
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG_BI_EMP", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRG_BI_EMP'


SQL> INSERT INTO employee (emp_id, birth_date) VALUES (1, DATE '1997-07-25');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and an elaborated answer. Error has been solved and learnt many new concepts from your answer as well. Happy coding :)

Comment: I added a trigger which checks age; have a look.

Comment: Just amazing, didnt know how to craete the triggers before. Now I got the logic and syntax both, perfectly. Thank you a trillion times. Much Happy now.

Comment: I just had one last question, out of curiosity. How do I code line below line in sql command line as I have to write entire query continuously in just one line. Is there any alternate way to it @Littlefoot.

Comment: Hm, where do you have to write entire query in a single line? Which tool do you use? Could you post a screenshot which shows what happens if you write piece of code, then press ENTER (so that you'd continue in the next line)?